# Webpack How to use the Target Attribute

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am new to Webpack and I am trying to figure out what target actually does.

In the docs, Webpack says:

> **Node**: Compile for usage in a Node.js-like environment (uses Node.js
>   require to load chunks)
>
> **Web**: Compile for usage in a browser-like environment (default)

But it is very abstract and does not tell what is the actual difference.

I notice that if a run the webpack config file with webpack-server in node mode, 
I get the error **required is not defined**, whereas 
if I just use webpack to export the files and then run the files independently, it runs fine. Does the target apply only to the webpack dev server?

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  target: "web", //node
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  entry: "./src/index",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "./bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    stats: "minimal",
    overlay: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    https: false
  },
}
```

I set the target attribute to "web" and ran it from backend. There is no difference with the target "node". It runs just fine. I see no purpose of the attribute

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very very simple example would be,

let's say you are creating a `React` app, which is a client side application and will be run at browser. You set the target to be `web`. (this is the default one)

If let's say it's a backend app, like an express app, it will not be run on browser, rather it will be started from `node` itself. So, you set the target to be `node`. Which *uses Node.js `require` to load chunks and not touch any built in modules like `fs` or `path`.*

Refer [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) for more options. Also [compare-webpack-target-bundles](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/compare-webpack-target-bundles) A great resource for testing and viewing different webpack targets. Also great for bug reporting.

Comment: I set the target attribute to "web" and ran it from backend. There is no difference with the target "node". The exported files from webpack are identical no matter the attribute's value.

Comment: Yes, it will be apparent when you use `fs` module and such which doesn't have browser counterpart. There are modules that doesn't work with browsers, you will see the difference there. Also the `__dirname` or `__filename` will be different.